# Font size isn't getting changed

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the font size of an element periodically but it isn't working.

I tried console.log() to get the size of the font but it returned some info in curly brackets. (I'm fairly new to JavaScript so I don't know if that is something which is expected). I tried looking up the documentation but even then it doesn't work.

JavaScript:

```
var text = document.getElementById("main");
var x = setInterval(incFont, 100);
console.log(document.getElementById("main").style.fontSize);
var size = parseInt(document.getElementById("main").style.fontSize, 10);

function incFont()
{
    size = size + 1;
    document.getElementById("main").style.fontSize = "" + size;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p id="main">
    Text-Growing
</p>
<script src="function.js"></script>
```

Output of console.log:

> {"notifyType":"consoleItemLog","message":{"message":"","styles":"","hasFormatString":true,"fileUrl":"file:///D:/170911092/Lab%203/function.js","lineNumber":3,"columnNumber":1}}

Comment: What does the markup look like for your `#main` element? Where is your `console.log()`? What exactly does the console message look like (you can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57470747/edit) to add screenshots)?

Comment: You're also missing the unit suffix for your [font-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size#Possible_approaches), ie `px`, `em`, etc

Comment: Added the HTML code and console.log output.

Will I need suffix if I am incrementing the size I got from the script?

Comment: console.log(size) before line 4 but I defined size before that.

Comment: There's no call to `console.log()` in the code you've showed us, so we are not sure what you are logging.

Answer (score 0):

Without some units, see [ways to specify the font size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size#Possible_approaches), you cannot update `style.fontSize`.

The object returned from `document.getElementById("content").style` is [CSSStyleDeclaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration), to set properties you can also use [setProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty).

The `.fontSize` style name is actually `font-size` so either of the following will update the CSS;

```
document.getElementById("main").style.fontSize = '12px';
document.getElementById("main").style.setProperty('font-size','12px');
```

Comment: It increments only once even though it loops many times. Even after adding units.

Comment: This does not retrieve the initial font-size of the element for which you need `getComputedStyle()` but there's already a duplicate link with all that information